# How to correctly unload graphic resources in XNA?

Tags: c#, .net, xna

I am developing a game that uses a massive amount of textures. Therefore I need to correctly unload textures when they are no longer used.

What is the corrrect way to unload textures (also vertex buffers, shaders, and other graphic resources)

I have heard that calling `Dispose()` is not the correct way to do so.

All textures are loaded via `Texture2D.FromStream` so I don't use `ContentManager` at all.

Comment: I noticed you are a long time user. Perhaps it is about time you start formatting your questions properly yourself? E.g. proper capitalization, punctuation. No longer writing 'thanks!' at the end, etc ... All the stuff you notice which gets edited out in your posts from time to time.

Comment: Did whoever tell you 'I have heard that calling Dispose() is not the correct way to do so.' mean in the context of XNA or in general? - It's bad advice either way. Dispose is there for a reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should unload content that a ContentManager has loaded by using ContentManager.Unload().

Textures and some other resources that you create yourself without going through ContentManager should be disposed (using Dispose()) in the Game.UnloadContent function.

Comment: thanks! yes i create all my textures via Texture2D.FromStream so i dont use ContentManager at all.